# How to find and change date in a string read from .doc

Tags: vb.net, date, replace

I'm writing a little application that will open my status reports that are in Word doc format. The document has several dates but the ones I want to find and change are like this:

- `Start Date: 05/14/2012`
- `End Date:  05/18/2012`

I'm writing this in VB.NET I can use the `String.IndexOf("Start Date: ")` method and it finds the word, but I was hoping to get the index position, then using `String.Length`, get the date field to modify it for each of the start and end date dates.

```
If (result.IndexOf("Start Date:") <> -1) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Start Date Found!")
End If
```

I thought about using RegEx but I don't think I'm that clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regex that will extract the dates for you:

`/(?:Start|End) Date: (\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/`

Each date will be in its own captured group once you run this regex on your string.

An example in VB:

```
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
Dim myRegex As New Regex("(?:Start|End) Date: (\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})")
Dim t As String = "Start Date: 05/14/2012 End Date: 05/18/2012"
myMatches = myRegex.Matches(t)
' Search for all the words in a string
Dim successfulMatch As Match
For Each successfulMatch In myMatches
   Debug.WriteLine(successfulMatch.Value)
Next
```

Comment: It sounds like he's new to RegEx.  Why not provide an example?

Comment: @StevenDoggart Not a bad idea I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for the example it really helped a lot. I'm very new to RegExp I tried several online helper tools and just couldn't get the pattern down since there are a lot of other dates in the report. I should be able to create a replace function to change that date. This community rocks!

Comment: You can actually do the replacement using regex as well. Look into the Regex class a bit more and see if you can figure it out, then come back if you need more help.

Comment: Before I come back on here an ask for more help, I want to try to figure it out on my own. I have trapped the two matches using an If then. _I don't really understand regexp grouping :(_ I'll do another match get just dates modify them then perform the replace using orig match to new date using that awesome date pattern you supplied me. I think that should work probably not the most elegant way though lol.